# 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found error

Tags: flutter, dart

I get "1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. (Documentation)  Try adding the missing arguments" error. What am I missing?

```
SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Text(
                  child: Text(_outputText),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Bro... Text widget doesn't have a child parameter. If you see the documentation, it needs a required string. In this case, your widget should be the following (considering your "_outputText" has a String type): `Text(_outputText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` widget doesnt have `child` params, it takes positional argument as string , the format will be

```dart
Text(
  _outputText,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20.0,
  ),
),
```

More about [`Text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)

Comment: That was quick, thank you. It worked

Comment: Glad to help, I will remand checking attached link for more